# Retrieve part of a Parse Object using Cloud Code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my `Users` class, I have a parameter called `passwordChanged`. I only want to return THAT ONE PARAMETER. I do not have the users `objectId`, just their `username` (under the context that I'm using this code in my app, I have to deal with this situation).

Given the code below, Cloud Code returns the entire object. How can I just return one parameter.

My second issue is that when I call the Cloud Code function and print `result` I get a `nill` value. But if I call the function again, I get the entire object. After playing around with my code I can 100% say that there is a delay in retrieving the data (obviously) but my app doesn't wait like it should (meanwhile if I use a general query within my app, my app waits). The reason why the second time around made `result` populated was because it was technically already populated from the previous time (but the delay caused the value to "appear" to be `nil`.) Please let me know if I'm not making sense!

Also, I'm fairly new to Cloud Code (JavaScript) so I probably made some obvious mistakes that I can't see.

App Code:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("checkAccountStatus", withParameters: ["username" : self.userText.text]) {
            (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                println (result) // First time around "nill" is displayed. Second time around, entire object data is displayed.
        }
```

Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkAccountStatus", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
query.first({
        success: function(getUserData) {

            var passwordChanged = getUserData;
            response.success(passwordChanged);

        },
        error: function(error) {

            response.error("There was an error");

        }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var passwordChanged = getUserData;
```

to:

```
var passwordChanged = getUserData.get("passwordChanged");
```

if "passwordChanged" is the name of the column that you want to return.

**UPDATED**

1: create an array for example to hold the values like `var results = [];`

2: create a query just as you above, and in that querys success handler add the columns that you want to the result array with `results.push("whatever_you_want");`

3: after that and inside the first querys success handler, create another query, and setup that with whatever you want to get

4: in the nested querys success handler, just append the results the same as in step 2.

Comment: Thanks! If you wouldn't mind helping me out a little more, how can I return two parameters/columns at the same time?